# Changing Copy UI in windows 7

Tags: user-interface, windows-7, copy, windows-shell

I want to change the default UI which is shown when a file/folder is copied or moved.
I looked up and found ICopyHook but it only verifies if the operation is to be allowed or not.
I want to make my own UI ( the copy-window ) when the operation happens.

I think writing a shell extension might do the trick, but I don't know how to write one, but most important where to hook it to ?

So finally the question is : Where to hook in Windows Shell to replace file copy window ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `IFileOperation::SetProgressDialog` method to provide a custom progress dialog for a particular `IFileOperation`. This customizes only the `IFileOperation` you call it for. It does not affect other people's `IFileOperation`. They get to choose how they want their progress to appear.